# How to detect bias between two experiments

Tags: r, bias

I need to analyse one dataset composed of two experiments. The goal is to identify sick individuals (animals) based on different parameters. These parameters have been collected on different farms (one time per farm), during two data recollection campaigns.

I have very limited information on one of the campaign, and I have some reasons to belive that the method used in some farms (but I don't know which) may have biased the results.

I identified two problems :

1. Sick animals are expected to have extreme values in most of the parameters, and are rare. So if I search for outliers, I will probably find only sick animals.
2. It is completely normal if some farms have  more sick animals than others (they are just more at risk)

I need to have an idea if there are bias in some farms. I know it sounds tricky, but does someone have a solution for this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "biased results"? In general, if you want the relationship between a predictor variable X and the outcome variable Y to vary for different levels of a categorical variable (such experimentID), one can include an interaction term X by experimentID. Not sure if this is the right approach here. Depends on what you mean by "bias in some farms".